# How to generate and attach PDF Invoice to Email?

Tags: java, android, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, sendgrid

I'm developing an e-commerce app. On triggering of a function the email is sending. But how to generate and attach PDF invoice along with the email? I'm using SEND GRID to send the emails.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an Android SendGrid library using Sendgrid's v3 Api. It handles File attachments and Uri conversion for emails.

https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.2.2'
}
```

I'm maintaining the library so if you have a request just create an Issue on Github!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to initiate an API call from the E-commerce app to the backend for the invoice. 
When the API call received at the server-side, create an invoice for that request, you can search for the pdf generation libraries or tutorials for Node.js. You can refer [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-pdfs-with-node-js-c2eb94034f01) for the pdf generation. And send an email attaching this created invoice. 
Send a success response to the E-commerce app for the request API. So that the E-commerce app can show a success message.

Comment: I need that in detail